# Broken PHP page security

Tags: php, security

I have this at the top of a navigation file which is included on every single page:

```
if (!is_logged_in()){
        login_error_redirect();
}
```

Here's that function:

```
function is_logged_in(){
    if(isset($_SESSION['GBuser']) && $_SESSION['GBuser'] > 0){
        return true;
    }
        return false;
}
```

Now this works insomuch as if you try to browse to a protected page you get redirected to the login page, but for some reason it doesn't apply if you supply a GET request, which allows you to completely bypass the whole thing. For instance, having just logged out (which calls session_destroy();), I can enter the following address and the item gets deleted:

```
../site/products.php?delete=20
```

What am I missing here? That products page includes the same navigation file with the security check above, but passing in a GET variable skips it completely for some reason.

EDIT: here's the top of products.php:

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/shopping/core/init.php';
include 'includes/head.php';
include 'includes/navigation.php';

//if the delete product button was clicked
if(isset($_GET['delete'])){
    $delete_id = (int)($_GET['delete']);
    $db->query("UPDATE products SET deleted = 1 WHERE id = '$delete_id'");
    header('Location: products.php');
}
```

And at the very top of navigation.php is the check:

```
if (!is_logged_in()){
        login_error_redirect();
}
```

Comment: May be delete function in products.php executes before navigation page.

Comment: Have you check session is start or not?

Comment: Add some logging to your function above and abort afterwards (`exit();`) to see if it is called at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `login_error_redirect()` actually redirects, you will have to add `exit` to stop the script after that function is called. By default, PHP will run all your code on the page regardless if you redirect at the top.

```
if (!is_logged_in()){
        login_error_redirect();
        exit;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that was incredibly simple! Thankyou so much.